# Objective-C Exception not thrown

Tags: objective-c, exception, nsarray

I've met a weird problem in my code.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
.
.
.
(added some objects into the array)
.
.
.
[array removeAllObjects];

NSObject *object = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

No matter I run it in Debug or Release mode, it did not crash and throw any exception in the console but "break" the current frame and directly go to the next frame.

if i catch the exception myself

```
@try {
    NSObject *object = [pathList objectAtIndex:0]];
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    ERR_HERE();
}
```

there really exists a NSRangeException.

It is dangerous for me as I don know when my app will goes wrong.
I just found this problem occasionally.

Why would this happened but not a crash with a exception message?

Comment: is `objectAtIndeo` just a typo here?

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions in an NSApplication generally won't crash it; but that it's not logged to the console is of course odd.

Aside from that, of course; there is the fact that if exceptions are thrown you are *probably* doing something wrong; or at least failing at making proper range and value checks for input; or, in the above example:

```
NSObject *object = nil;

if ([array count])
  object = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```